# Discount mask with regex

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible to create a 'dynamic' discount mask that takes % or numbers as discount values? What is the simple way to do this?
 the samples of valide input: -25% or 0.25 or -5$ not 0 and two digit after dot

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Please read [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) and revise your question accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by a "dynamic" discount mask? Are you looking to match 10%, 15%, 100% etc using regex?

Comment: not only percentage((  take a look at edited text

Comment: Still not clear. What do you mean by `dynamic`? Mask? What mask? What are the outputs? In what context? Why regex? What are you trying to achieve? I can see you didn't read the link I posted...

Comment: dynamic - perhaps the wrong word. the universal - more suitable here/ sorry Oded

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@"(\+|-)?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)%?"
```

It will find:

```
123.23
12.4%
.34
.34%
45.
45.%
8
7%
34
34%
+2.55%
-1.75%
```

---

**UPDATE**

and with ...

```
@"(\+|-)?(\d+(,\d{3})*(?!\d)(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)%?"
```

... you can include thousands separators as well.

---

I must confess that my second regex expression looks like a cat had walked accross my keyboard. Here the explanation

`(\+|-)?` optionally `?` a plus or a minus sign.

`\d+(,\d{3})*(?!\d)(\.\d*)?` one or more digits `\d+` followed by any number of thousands separators plus three digits `(,\d{3})*`, not followed by any digit `(?!\d)` in order to disallow four digits in sequence, optionally followed by a decimal point and any number of digits `(\.\d*)?`.

`|\.\d+` or alternatively a decimal point followed by at least one digit.

`%?` finally an optional percent sign.

Comment: and how about -10 ? (minus ten dollars, not percents)

Comment: @curiousity: I added `(\+|-)?` three minutes ago.

Comment: Your `(,?\d)*` token is off. This will allow `123,4,5,6`. It also allows `123.`, with nothing after the dot.

Comment: My intention is to allow `.5` for `0.5` and `1.` for `1`. If you are parsing a user input this might make sense. I corrected the thousands separators part to be more accurate.

Comment: The thousands separators look right now. The problem is that your `(\.\d*)` token doesn't require any numerals after the period. You'd be better off using `(\.\d+)` instead. If not for the commas, you could get away with `\d*(\.\d+)?` for the numeral part, but I think you can still simplify it as `\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?|\.\d+` and be more precise.

Comment: Update: `(?!\d)` isn't doing anything for you, I'm pretty sure that will always return true. There can't be a digit after that position, only `.`, `%`, or the end of the line.

Comment: As I say before, allowing ".5" or "1." was intentional. As for the `(?!\d)`: Try this "1,2508.50". It will disallow the "8" after the "250" (`\d{3}`). But keep in mind that we only want to find numbers and not validate them. Since the OP is giving us very little information on the kind of text used as input, it is tedious to elaborate details that might not be required at all.

Comment: Ah, I see. I wouldn't consider `1.` to be valid, but that's personal preference and I see now that it was intentional. But I also see what you're trying to do with the lookahead now, and you're not using it correctly. You would use `(,\d{3}(?!\d))*` to block more than 3 digits (notice it's inside the outer parentheses). However, the lookahead still isn't necessary because of the rest of the pattern. Any comma in the input *must* be followed by 3 and only 3 digits, even if you remove the lookahead (try it).

Comment: It still behaves differently. Without the lookahead it returns "1,250" and "8.25"  for the pattern "1,2508.25". With the lookahead it returns "1" and then "2508.25". But discount values will hardly exceed 100% anyway, so the thousands separator stuff can be dropped anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want something like this:

```
@"^[+-]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+[%$]?$"
```

That's partly based on your example of `-5$`. Usually, though, the `$` would go in front, so you'd want something like:

```
@"^(?:\$(?!.*%))?[+-]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+%?$"
```

That would allow `$-5.00`, `10`, or `+20%`, but block `$5%`.

### Edit:

Running with **Olivier**'s idea of allowing commas:

```
@"^(\$(?!.*%))?[+-]?(\d{1,3}((,\d{3})*|\d*))?(\.\d+)?\b%?$"
```

Expanded to make it easier to understand:

```
@"^               #Require matching from the beginning of the line
(\$(?!.*%))?      #Optionally allow a $ here, but only if there's no % later on.
[+-]?             #Optionally allow + or - at the beginning
(
  \d{1,3}         #Covers the first three numerals
  ((,\d{3})*|\d*) #Allow numbers in 1,234,567 format, or simply a long string of numerals with no commas
)?                #Allow for a decimal with no leading digits    
(\.\d+)?          #Optionally allow a period, but only with numerals behind it
\b                #Word break (a sneaky way to require at least one numeral before this position, thus preventing an empty string)
%?                #Optionally allow %
$"                #End of line
```